# Using class with PDO

Tags: php, class, pdo

I decided to use PDO after recommends here and i found this code below. Those codes are good enough to prevent SQl injection? And class is better option?

```
<?
class database {

private $hostname;
private $database;
private $username;
private $password;
private $pdo;
function __construct($hostname, $database, $username, $password) {

$this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->hostname};port={$this->port};dbname={$this->database}", $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

} catch(PDOException $e) {

print "<b>Error - Connection Failed: </b>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
}

public function query($query, $bind = null) {
global $pdo;

$this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$this->statement->execute($bind);
}



$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$database->query('INSERT INTO users_inactive(verCode, username, password, email, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array($verCode, $username, $password, $email, $date));

$success[] = "You account has been created!";

?>
```

Comment: Right at a glance I can spot at least 3 problems with this code. Don't use it.

Comment: Quick question: did you actually *initialize* `$database` as a `database`-class object before using it?

Comment: Yes Palladium, code currently working without problem

$database = new database("localhost", "test", "root", "rootpass");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code contains syntax errors, shorthands and globals. No, it's not good enough to use.